openVPN doesn't route into Azure
I installed a centos machine in Azure and its ip address is 10.5.0.4 then I installed an openVPN machine in Azure and its private address is 10.6.0.4 .I did peering between centOS and openVPN networks and it works fine, so I can ping each other.
When I connect to openVPN with my computer, my local computer is given the private ip address 10.6.0.2 . I can ping from 10.6.0.2 to 10.6.0.4 thats fine but I can't ping from 10.6.0.2 to 10.5.0.4. I think that openVPN doesn't route 10.6.0.2 traffic to 10.5.0.4. How can I do this routing?

Try adding ip forwarding to the server on which openVPN is installed. This could be done by editing the /etc/sysctl.conf file:
nano /etc/systctl.conf

Add the following line:
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

Save the file changes and then run the following command to apply the changes:
sudo sysctl -p

You may also need to add the static route to the OpenVPN server. This way, the OpenVPN server will know how to forward traffic to the CentOS machine's network.
sudo ip route add 10.5.0.0/24 via 10.5.0.4 dev eth0

Where necessary, replace eth0 with the actual network interface name if it's different
Furthermore, you need to push a route to the OpenVPN clients so that they know how to reach the CentOS machine's network: Edit the OpenVPN server configuration file, usually located at /etc/openvpn/server.conf, and add the following line:
push "route 10.5.0.0 255.255.255.0"

Now, restart your OpenVPN server:
sudo systemctl restart openvpn@server

